# Find stepwise values based on a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set that generates a dollar amount for an individual. I need a way to calculate commissions on this amount using the following table of commission tiers:

```
     SPREAD
 Min     |   Max   | Commission%
  __________________________________
   -       |  3,000  | 2.00%
 3,001   |  6,000  | 3.00%
 6,001   | 10,000  | 5.00%
10,001  | 15,000  | 6.00%
15,001  | 20,000  | 7.50%
20,001  |   +     | 10.00%
```

I need to be able to calculate the $ amount of the commission in a stepwise fashion. So if an individual has $6500 total Spread, I need it broken down so that they get 2% of $3000 ($0-$3000 tier), 3% of $3000 ($3001-$6000 tier), and 5% of 500 ($6001-$10000 tier). 
So ultimately I'd like a formula that gives the $ amount at each tier.

**

### EDIT:

**

I have worked out an IF formula that seems to work. Below is the edited able:

```
  Col C     Col D      Col E

 Min     |   Max   | Commission% |  Commission $
 __________________________________
   -     |  3,000  | 2.00%       |  60
 3,001   |  6,000  | 3.00%       |  89.97
 6,001   | 10,000  | 5.00%       |  24.95
10,001   | 15,000  | 6.00%       |  0
15,001   | 20,000  | 7.50%       |  0
20,001   |   +     | 10.00%      |  0

                          Total  |  174.92
```

I tweaked the final max amount to equal an impossibly huge number, then filled in all of the commission $ fields using this following formula:

```
=IF($B$17>D3,(D3-C3)*E3,IF((($B$17-C3)*E3)<0,"0",$B$17-C3)*E3)
```

Where B17 was the original dollar amount of the individual. I then summed the values at each tier to find the total.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  When asking a question for code you should provide the code you've tried and point out what you need help with. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**

I have worked out an IF formula that seems to work. Below is the edited able:

```
  Col C     Col D      Col E

 Min     |   Max   | Commission% |  Commission $
 __________________________________
   -     |  3,000  | 2.00%       |  60
 3,001   |  6,000  | 3.00%       |  89.97
 6,001   | 10,000  | 5.00%       |  24.95
10,001   | 15,000  | 6.00%       |  0
15,001   | 20,000  | 7.50%       |  0
20,001   |   +     | 10.00%      |  0

                      Total  |  174.92
```

I tweaked the final max amount to equal an impossibly huge number, then filled in all of the commission $ fields using this following formula:

```
=IF($B$17>D3,(D3-C3)*E3,IF((($B$17-C3)*E3)<0,"0",$B$17-C3)*E3)
```

Where B17 was the original dollar amount of the individual. I then summed the values at each tier to find the total.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a formula that should work.

It uses a helper cell just to simplify the formula.  If you wanted to avoid the helper cell you could just paste that formula in anywhere the total commission references B10.

Gordon

helper cell

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(A10,$B$2:$B$7,1),0)
```

total commission

```
=IF(B10=0,0,SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(B2,0,0,B10),OFFSET(C2,0,0,B10))-SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(A2,0,0,B10),OFFSET(C2,0,0,B10)))+(A10-OFFSET(A2,B10,0))*OFFSET(C2,B10,0)
```

[image]